# Looping through array and removing elements of specific types d3.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, d3.js

`data` is an array that contains elements of different types. I want to loop through this array and remove all elements with the type `A` and type `B`. This is what I have so far:

```
for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){ 
    if (i.type === "A"|| i.type === "B") {
        data.splice(i, 1);
    }   
}
```

It doesnt remove anything even though some are of types `A` or `B`.

Can someone tell me why is this wrong and how I should fix it please!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you just tried the DELETE command? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Comment: `i` is a number, you are accessing a type property over it. Is is `data[i].type`?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy that was it!! thank you so much I dont know why I didnt think of that! Really appreciate the quick response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The problem

You actually have two errors in your code :

1. You're looping forwards. If you want to splice an array while looping through its elements, you need to loop backwards.
2. `i.type` should be `data[i].type`. `i` is just a number and doesn't even have a `type` property.

#### Fixed code

```
for(var i = data.length-1; i >= 0; i--){ 
    if (data[i].type === "A"|| data[i].type === "B") {
        data.splice(i, 1);
    }   
}
```

#### A demo

```js
var data = [
    { value : 'Tom', type : 'A' },
    { value : 'Susan', type : 'C' },
    { value : 'Frank', type : 'B' },
    { value : 'Hakeem', type : 'A' },
    { value : 'Ali', type : 'C' },
    { value : 'Thomas', type : 'B' },
    { value : 'An', type : 'D' }
];

for(var i = data.length-1; i >= 0; i--){ 
    if (data[i].type === "A"|| data[i].type === "B") {
        data.splice(i, 1);
    }   
}

document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/aonz8qqq/1/))

---

#### Note

You'll actually get better performance if - instead of removing all objects with `data[i].type === "A"|| data[i].type === "B"` - you just create a new array and just copy all values from your original array array where `data[i].type !== "A" && data[i].type !== "B"` :

```js
var data = [
    { value : 'Tom', type : 'A' },
    { value : 'Susan', type : 'C' },
    { value : 'Frank', type : 'B' },
    { value : 'Hakeem', type : 'A' },
    { value : 'Ali', type : 'C' },
    { value : 'Thomas', type : 'B' },
    { value : 'An', type : 'D' }
];

var copy = [];
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){ 
    if (data[i].type !== "A" && data[i].type !== "B") {
        copy.push(data[i]);
    }   
}
data = copy;

document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/aonz8qqq/2/))

Comment: appreciate that a lot! I got ahead of myself thinking that was the solution! very good and clear explanation! @JohnSlegers

Comment: @JohnPower : I just added a note at the bottom of my answer with an alternative implementation, which gives you better performance.

Answer (score 1):

Looping the array while splicing it is problematic, instead use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) here:

```
var filteredData = data.filter(function(d){
    return !(i.type === "A"|| i.type === "B");
});
```

Comment: Looping an array while splicing is not a problem, as long as you loop backwards instead of forwards.

Comment: @JohnSlegers, true, but still going to argue that `filter` is the better way to do this.  It's just easier to read and cleaner code.

Comment: A downside of `filter` is that the earliest version of IE to support it is IE9. And while it's faster than `splice`, it's still slower than just creating a new array and copying the relevant bits -> https://jsperf.com/splice-vs-filter